# Spherical Harmonics basis for $L_2(S^2)$, what about the space of functions on the sphere of radius R

Tags: change-of-basis, spherical-harmonics

It is well know that the spherical harmonics $Y_{l,m}(\theta,\varphi)$ are basis for $L_2(S^2)$ ( All square integrable functions on the unit sphere ) .

What about the basis of the space of all square integrable functions on the sphere of radius R ? Can we say this basis is the set of the same spherical harmonics of the case of the unit sphere ?

Comment: I think yes. It is just a result of dilatation

Answer (score 2):

In the space $L^2(S^1)$, we already have the harmonics (orthogonal basis) of the Fourier series of functions of **any period $T$**:

$$e_n(x)=(\sqrt T)^{-1}e^{2\pi inx/T}$$

If $T\to\infty$, then the Fourier series will become the Fourier transform. I wouldn't expect the spherical harmonics be different to the Fourier series, though I don't have the exact formula. Perhaps there will be a scale factor in the coefficient and the exponential.